# Want to add string when we found trigonometry operator in js

Tags: javascript

I want to attach a string (x) when we found a sin cos tan or any trigonometry operator

```
const input = 'sin(45)+cos(45)'
```

i want final expression as

```
const output = 'x.sin(45)+x.cos(45)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Regex to search and replace a pattern in a a string. Look at Regex to make your pattern match your needs.

```js
const input = 'sin(45)+cos(45)';
const regex = /(sin)|(cos)|(tan)/gi;

console.log(input.replace(regex, 'x.$&')); // output: "x.sin(45)+x.cos(45)"
```

The regex variable will be used to match string 'sin' OR string 'cos' OR string 'tan'. With the /gi (flags) at the end, the Regex will search all occurrences (g) and will ignore case (i).

In the replace function 'x.$&' mean: replace pattern found by regex with 'x.$&' ('x.' the string your want, '$&' mean to add the pattern found ('cos' for example), without it your ouput will "x.(45)+x.(45)" for the example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple functions to achieve this:

```js
const input = 'sin(45)+cos(45)';

var i = input.indexOf('sin');
var inter = input.slice(0, i) + "x." + input.slice(i);
console.log(inter);

var j = inter.indexOf('cos');
var output = inter.slice(0, j) + "x." + inter.slice(j);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```js
const input = 'sin(45)+cos(45)'

input.split(/(cos|sin)/).map((str) => ['sin', 'cos'].includes(str) ? `x.${str}` : str).join('')
```